# Entity field condition not to be mandatory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entity

I have a form that contains data like: `name`, `description`, `meta_title`, `meta_keywords`, `meta_description`.
In entity class, i have added this validations:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{name.notblank}")
@Size(min = 2, max = 250, message = "{name.size}")
@Column( name = "pgs_name")
private String name;

@NotBlank(message = "{description.notblank}")
@Size(min = 10, message = "{description.size}")
@Column( name = "pgs_description")
private String description;

@Nullable
@Size(min = 2, max = 250, message = "{meta_title.size}")
@Column( name = "pgs_meta_title")
private String meta_title;

@Nullable
@Size(min = 2, max = 250, message = "{meta_keywords.size}")
@Column( name = "pgs_meta_keywords")
private String meta_keywords;

@Nullable
@Size(min = 2, max = 250, message = "{meta_description.size}")
@Column( name = "pgs_meta_description")
private String meta_description;
```

What i want, if, for example, field `meta_title` is completed, then to check if the condition: `@Size(min = 2, max = 250, message = "{meta_title.size}")` is respected, else if nothing is completed, then, no problem, the field in database will be empty.

The problem is that hibernate don't care about `@Nullable` and it automatically validate the field with `@Size` annotation.

So, what annotation i can use for my problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your custom validation annotation and a class that implements `ConstraintValidator`. By overriding its `isValid` method you can add your custom logic to your custom annotation. Check out [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator) example.